# Tensorflow-gpu performance drop

Tags: tensorflow

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code**: No
- **OS Platform and Distribution**: Windows 10 64-bit
- **TensorFlow installed from**: binary
- **TensorFlow version**: 1.6.0
- **Python version**: 3.6.3
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 9.0
- **GPU model and memory**: GeForce GTX 780, 3Gb

Using Keras in Python with tensorflow-gpu backend. Worked fine for weeks until a few days ago, when I have suffered a huge performance drop.

When Tensorflow is initialising, it all appears to work correctly and finds my GPU as normal. Output:

```
2018-04-05 02:08:32.791893: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 780 major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0195
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 3.00GiB freeMemory: 2.46GiB
2018-04-05 02:08:32.792360: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-04-05 02:08:33.132555: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2187 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 780, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
```

But whereas before with exactly the same model on the same data, each epoch took about 2-3 seconds, they now take ~17 seconds.

I had a look in Task Manager, and my IDE shows to be using GPU Engine - "GPU 0 - Copy". Also at the beginning of each epoch, the GPU will go under ~70% load for about a second, but then the load switches over to my CPU and Memory for the remaining 15 seconds or so and the GPU goes back down to its idle load around 2%.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Also let me know if I can provide more information